# Python: Fix missing import with a monkey patch

Tags: python, gdb, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkey patch a missing import. The old_invoke() still does not get the import.
In case it is relevant, `MyClass` is a `gdb.Command`.

```
(gdb) pi
>>> import mymodule
>>> old_invoke = mymodule.MyClass.invoke
>>> def new_invoke(self, *k, **kw):
...   print("New invoke")
...   import getopt
...   old_invoke(self, *k, **kw)
...
>>> mymodule.MyClass.invoke = new_invoke
>>>
(gdb) my_gdb_command
New invoke
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> name 'getopt' is not defined:
Error occurred in Python: name 'getopt' is not defined
```

Also, in case it is relevant, the initial files and sourcing looks something like this:

mymodule.py:

```
import gdb
class MyClass(gdb.Command):
   ...

   def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
      options, remainder = getopt.getopt(args, 'p:s:t:o:')
      ...

MyClass()
```

myothermodule.py:

```
import mymodule
...
```

Sourcing the above

```
(gdb) source myothermodule.py
```

Comment: There should be a `import getopt` in the MyClass file, right?

Comment: A function holds a reference to the module object it was defined in and searches for global names in this module's namespace. A function doesn't care about the local or other namespaces of the function which called it.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to add `getopt` to `mymodule`.

Comment: @MirzaAtlı. Correct

Comment: @MichaelButscher. Yes, but not in an automated way that I need. I am unable to modify all copies of mymodule readily.

Comment: @C.Nivs. Worked perfect thanks! Found I was also missing another import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`old_invoke` is trying to reference `mymodule`'s `getopt`, which doesn't exist. You need:

```py
>>> import mymodule
>>> old_invoke = mymodule.MyClass.invoke
>>> def new_invoke(self, *k, **kw):
...   print("New invoke")
...   import getopt
...   
...   # here
...   mymodule.getopt = getopt
...   
...   old_invoke(self, *k, **kw)
...
>>> mymodule.MyClass.invoke = new_invoke
```

But, realistically, you should just have an `import getopt` in `mymodule`:

```py
# mymodule.py
import getopt
...
```

Then your function is simply:

```py
>>> import mymodule
>>> old_invoke = mymodule.MyClass.invoke
>>> def new_invoke(self, *k, **kw):
...   print("New invoke")
...   old_invoke(self, *k, **kw)
...
>>> mymodule.MyClass.invoke = new_invoke
```

### Addendum

As another note, using `import` in a function isn't generally recommended. Unless you are only calling this function once (and even then, why?), every time you call the function you are attempting to load a module, which at best will always do a check against `sys.modules` when you probably don't have to.

Have the `import getopt` at the top of the script:

```py
import getopt
import mymodule

mymodule.getopt = getopt
```

Which is where you'd probably expect this to be anyways

Comment: Thanks! `mymodule.getopt = getopt` is what I needed for my purposes.  Was also thinking of using `inspect` but glad that this worked instead.